# Apollo Mutation component with OptimisticResponse creates duplicate records until reload

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

When using OptimisticResponse in an Apollo Client Mutation component, the update function gets called twice correctly - once with the OptimisticResponse and once with the data returned from my db - but duplicate entries are added until the page is refreshed. This is noticeable when you slow the Network speed to Slow 3G. The duplicate entries disappear on page reload, and aren't a problem for fast Network speeds.

Here's my repo: https://github.com/cmoses8626/apollo

Below is my Mutation component. You'll notice I have to add a bogus temporary ID in the OptimisticResponse - so secondary question here: how can I get around this? Seems like a code smell.

```
<Mutation
    mutation={CREATE_RESOLUTION}
    update={(cache, { data: { createResolution } }) => {
      const { resolutions } = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_RESOLUTIONS });
      console.log(createResolution);
      cache.writeQuery({
        query: GET_RESOLUTIONS,
        data: { resolutions: resolutions.concat([createResolution]) }
      });
    }}
  >
    {mutate => (
      <div>
        <form
          onSubmit={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (input.value) {
              mutate({
                variables: { name: input.value },
                optimisticResponse: {
                  __typename: "Mutation",
                  createResolution: {
                    __typename: "Resolution",
                    name: input.value,
                    _id: "123"
                  }
                }
              });
              input.value = "";
            }
          }}
        >
          <input
            placeholder="Add resolution"
            ref={node => {
              input = node;
            }}
          />
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )}
  </Mutation>
```

Comment: I'm sure this is not really helpful, but your code looks like it should work. GET_RESOLUTIONS is fetching a list of resolutions which should replace the local cache when the real answer comes in (so the fake id should not be a problem). Are you using the latest version of Apollo and other related deps?

Comment: Thanks, Mikael. Updated (44 packages!) but still no change in duplicate entries before page refresh.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue (I'm experiencing the exact same thing)?

Comment: @TheoG I haven't looked at the code in a while, but check out this thread in Spectrum (Apollo is moving their community off Slack) that seems to answer the question: https://spectrum.chat/?t=4e16ba7d-97a2-40cb-ba2f-bbd22f2228dc